# two dimensional checkbox in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a HTML form with checkbox like this, but I am struggle to turn them into two dimensional

```
<input type="checkbox" id="orange" name="fruit1" value="orange">
<input type="checkbox" id="banana" name="fruit2" value="banana">
<input type="checkbox" id="apple" name="fruit3" value="apple">
<input type="checkbox" id="pear" name="fruit4" value="pear">

<input type="checkbox" id="ripe" name="feature1" value="ripe">
<input type="checkbox" id="price" name="feature2" value="price">
<input type="checkbox" id="quantity" name="feature3" value="quantity">
<input type="checkbox" id="cost" name="feature4" value="cost">
```

What I want is something like this

|  | orange | banana | apple | pear |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ripe | Tick |  |  |  |
| price | Tick | Tick |  | Tick |
| quantity |  | Tick | Tick |  |
| cost |  |  |  | Tick |

Any method to achieve this?

Comment: if i understood you right you will build a matrix where you can check and uncheck the fields?

Comment: @MaikLowrey yeah, that's what I want to do, any suggestions?

Comment: Consider a table for your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build an table like below

```
<form method="POST">
      
    <table class="table table-bordered ">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>orange</th>
            <th>banana</th>
            <th>apple</th>
            <th>pear</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>ripe</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="matrix[ripe][]" value="orange"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="matrix[ripe][]" value="banana"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="matrix[ripe][]" value="apple"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="matrix[ripe][]" value="pear"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>price</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="matrix[price][]" value="orange"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="matrix[price][]" value="banana"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="matrix[price][]" value="apple"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="matrix[price][]" value="pear"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>quantity</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="matrix[quantity][]" value="orange"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="matrix[quantity][]" value="banana"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="matrix[quantity][]" value="apple"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="matrix[quantity][]" value="pear"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cost</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="matrix[cost][]" value="orange"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="matrix[cost][]" value="banana"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="matrix[cost][]" value="apple"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="matrix[cost][]" value="pear"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
        <button type="submit">sub</button>
    </form>
```

if you submit form like below
[image]

Output of the form like below

[image]

Updated :if you are using Laravel

```
@php
    $fruits=[
    'orange',
    'banana',
    'apple',
    'pear'
];

    $features=['ripe','price','quantity','cost'];
    @endphp

    <form method="POST">
        @csrf
    <table class="table table-bordered ">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            @foreach($fruits as $fruit)
            <th>{{$fruit}}</th>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($features as $value)
        <tr>

            <td>{{$value}}</td>
            @foreach($fruits as $fruit)
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="matrix[{{$value}}][]" value="{{$fruit}}"></td>
            @endforeach


        </tr>
        @endforeach

        </tbody>
    </table>
        <button type="submit">sub</button>
    </form>
```

using jquery

```
<div id="dynamic-content"></div>
<script>
    let fruits=[
        'orange',
        'banana',
        'apple',
        'pear'
    ];

    let features=['ripe','price','quantity','cost'];
    $.each(features , function(index, val) {
        console.log(index, val)
    });

    let html=`<table class="table table-bordered ">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>`;
    $.each(features , function(index, val) {
        html += ` <tr>

            <td>${val}</td>`;
        $.each(fruits, function (index, val) {
            html += `<td><input type="checkbox"  name="matrix[${val}][]" value="${val}"></td>`;
        })
    })

    html+=`</tr></tbody>
    </table>`;
    $('#dynamic-content').html(html)
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, and btw, is it possible to loop over fruit to build the rows?

Comment: @XJTLUmedia are you using php ?

Comment: No, could it be achieved by using Javascript and Jquery?

Comment: @XJTLUmedia i have updated answer. try debuging and solve as per your requirement

Comment: wow thanks, really detailed answers, very helpful

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you want to do. Maybe this works?

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Orange</th>
            <th>Banana</th>
            <th>Apple</th>
            <th>Pear</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>ripe</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="orange_ripe" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="Banana_ripe" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="Apple_ripe" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="Pear_ripe" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>price</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="orange_price" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="Banana_price" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="Apple_price" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="Pear_price" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>quantity</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="orange_quantity" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="Banana_quantity" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="Apple_quantity" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="Pear_quantity" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cost</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="orange_cost" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="Banana_cost" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="Apple_cost" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="Pear_cost" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: uh, yeah, I know this works, but I mean doing it javascript way. Because the data I got is from another page using AJAX. I don't mean to do it one by one, but thank you anyway

Comment: What does the data you're receiving look like?

Comment: two arrays, one is fruit, another one is feature. They are generated in first page by multiple select box

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to build a table and input in every cell a inputfield with the value `x/y`.